# See information about the environment in DrRacket debugger

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I have started reading Structure and Implementation of Computer Programs and in the first exercise on it (https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/psets/ps1/readme.html) it talks about the text-editing system Edwin. I am using DrRacket since I saw it suggested as a good alternative to Edwin for modern-day Windows 10. However, I don't see any equivalent to the following information about the environment:

```
ENVIRONMENT named: (user)
    p1 = #[compound-procedure 31 p1]
    p3 = #[compound-procedure 32 p3]
    p2 = #[compound-procedure 27 p2]
==> ENVIRONMENT created by the procedure: P1
      x = 1
      y = 2
```

Where can I find information about the environment itself and not just have access to the stack and the variables, especially since in the exercise it says that environments will be explored more thoroughly, and I'd like to know if DrRacket is actually good enough for me to use throughout the whole book or to just get comfortable with another IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DrRacket is good enough.  I've completed nearly all the exercises in the book and I only used DrRacket.  You can use the [SICP package](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html) for DrRacket so the language more closely matches the SICP flavour of scheme in the book.  This will also add sicp-pict support for the exercises in Chapter 2.

You don't need to view the environment within DrRacket.  In Chapter 3 you'll encounter environment diagrams - but these are pencil and paper excercises.  In Chapter 4 you will implement the environment yourself as part of implementing scheme.  When it refers to exploring the environment it may mean exploring the environment model of evaluation from the academic perspective (what is it?, why do we have it?, what are its pros and cons?).

I'm not familiar with the "Sample Programming Assignments", besides containing useful material they may also have the potential to complicate things.  E.g. I notice the 1.1 code uses lambdas that aren't introduced until 1.3 in the book.